# Find $a\in \mathbb{R}$ for which $a\cdot \left(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right)^2-3\cdot\frac{a}{1+x^2}+1=0$ will have all roots imaginary

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

> Find $a\in  \mathbb{R}$ for which $a\cdot \left(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right)^2-3\cdot\frac{a}{1+x^2}+1=0$ will have all roots imaginary.

My attempt is as follows:-

Let $t=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$, and let's find out its range for which x is imaginary

$$t=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$
$$(1+x^2)\cdot t=1$$
$$tx^2+t-1=0$$
$$D<0$$

$$0-4t(t-1)<0$$
$$t(t-1)>0$$
$$t\in (-\infty,0)\quad \cup \quad (1,\infty)$$

So for the equation $at^2-3at+1=0$, we have to find such values of a for which $t\in (-\infty,0) \cup  (1,\infty)$. As $t$ should be real,so

$$D\geq 0\Leftrightarrow 9a^2-4a\geq 0\Leftrightarrow a(9a-4)\geq0$$
$$a\in \left(-\infty,0\right] \cup \left[\frac{4}{9},\infty\right)$$

But if we place $a=0$ in the quadratic equation in $t$, then $0+0+1=0$, which is not possible hence $a\in \left(-\infty,0\right) \cup \left[\frac{4}{9},\infty\right)$.

Now as we know that roots of quadratic equation $at^2-3at+1=0$ should lie in $(-\infty,0)\cup  (1,\infty)$. So

Case 1 : **When both roots are negative**

$$af(0)>0$$
$$a>0$$

$0$ is greater than both the roots, so 
$0>(a+b)/2$ where a and b are roots.
$$0>\frac{3a}{2a}$$
$$0>\frac{3}{2}$$

So $a\in \phi$ for first case

Case 2: **When both roots are greater than $1$**

$$af(1)>0$$
$$a(a-3a+1)>0$$
$$a(2a-1)<0$$
$$a\in \left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

$1$ should lie before the roots on the x-axis, so $1<\frac{a+b}{2}$
$$1<\frac{3a}{2a}$$
$$1<\frac{3}{2}$$

So $a\in \left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)$ for the second case

Case 3: **When one root is greater than $1$ and another is negative:**

$$af(0)<0\quad \cap \quad af(1)<0$$
$$a<0\quad \cap\quad a(a-3a+1)<0$$
$$a<0\quad \cap \quad a(2a-1)>0$$
$$a\in \left(-\infty,0\right)$$

Hence $a\in \left(-\infty,0\right) \cup \left[\frac{4}{9},\frac{1}{2}\right)$ 
but answer is $a\in \left(-\infty,\frac{1}{2}\right)$

What mistake I am doing, I thought about it a lot but didn't get any breakthroughs. Please help me in this.

Comment: I haven't read everything, but there is a minor mistake in the beginning that luckily does not yield something wrong. Indeed, it is not true that the parametric (in t) equation (in x) has imaginary solutions iff the discriminant is < 0. This would hold if t was real, but it is *complex*. You should instead write the entire solution of the equation and verify if it is real. In this case you are lucky, because if $x$ is imaginary then $t=1/(1+x^2)$ is real. You sure that maybe you made this error somewhere else?

Comment: I have checked multiple times, but didn't find anything.

Comment: I assumed that roots will be complex

Answer (score 3):

In your proof you have excluded the interval $(0,4/9)$. Why? For example if $a=1/3\in(0,4/9)$ then the equation becomes
$$\frac{1+3x^2+3x^4}{(1+x^2)^2}=0$$
which has not real roots because the l.h.s. is always positive. Hence $1/3$ should be included in the required set.

If $z(x)=1/(1+x^2)$ then $z(\mathbb{R})=(0,1]$. Let $p(z)=az^2-3az+1$ then
we have to find for which real $a$, $p((0,1])$ does not contain $0$.
We have $3$ cases according to the sign of $a$.

1) If $a>0$ then $p$ is decreasing in $(-\infty,3/2)$ and $p((0,1])=[-2a+1,1)$ and therefore $0\not \in [-2a+1,1)$ iff $-2a+1>0$ iff $a<1/2$.

2) If $a<0$ then $p$ is increasing in $(-\infty,3/2)$ and $p((0,1])=(1,-2a+1]$ and therefore $0\not \in (1,-2a+1]$ for all  $a<0$.

3) If $a=0$ then $p$ is identically $1$ and therefore it is never zero.

We may conclude that the given equation has not real roots if and only if $a\in \left(-\infty,\frac{1}{2}\right)$.

Comment: can you tell what is wrong in my solution, I checked it multiple times but didn't get the mistake.

Comment: In your proof, at the first step  you have excluded the interval $(0,4/9)$. Why? I don't see any reason to do that!

Comment: well $t\in \left(-\infty,0\right) \cup \left(1,\infty\right)$ if x has to be imaginary and for equation $at^2-3at+1$ to have real roots, $D>=0$

Comment: Take $a=1/3$ then the equation becomes
$\frac{1+3x^2+3x^4}{(1+x^2)^2}=0.$ 
$t=1/(1+x^2)$ is imaginery and also $x$ is imaginery.

Comment: so how should we get the range for $t=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ if t can also be imaginary?

Comment: The image of a complex function is not easy to find in general. I think it is easier to assume $x$ real and prove that the equation can not be zero.

Comment: see in your solution you have said that $z\in (0,1]$ if $x$ has to be real, so for $z\in (0,1]$,  $a\cdot p(0)>0$ and $0<\frac{3}{2}$ and $a\cdot p(1)>=0$ and $1>=\frac{3}{2}$ and $D>=0$ where $\frac{3}{2}$ is the average of roots, hence for no value of a, x can be real, it means for all values of a, x is imaginary, right?

Comment: @user3290550 The sum of the roots is $3$. $3/2$ is the $x$-coordinate of the vertex. Are talking about the case $a>0$ or $a<0$?

Comment: If sum of roots is 3, then their average will be 3/2 right, thats what I have written.
and I have covered for a>0, and a<0 if you see I am multiplying a with p(0) and p(1), and if roots $\in(0,1] $, then their sum cannot be 3, thats why for no value of a ,if  x is real

Comment: OK. So what are your conclusions? Note that $3/2>1$ (not $1>=\frac{3}{2}$)

Comment: so for all values of a, x will be complex, but we have to find those values of a for which real part of the complex number is zero

Comment: thats why I am saying for no value of a, x can be real, because we are getting the contradiction

Comment: No. For example if $a=2$ then there is a real root $x=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{7}}$.

Comment: If $a<1/2$ there are NO real roots. If $a=1/2$ there is ONE double real root $x=0$ (and two complex roots), if $a>1/2$ there are TWO real roots (and two complex roots).

Comment: no bro ,  if $a=2$, then $2z^2-6z+1=0$, then $z=\frac{3+\sqrt{7}}{2}$ or $z=\frac{3-\sqrt{7}}{2}$, both are positive roots, then find value of $x$ for $z=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$, you will get x as imaginary number

Comment: NO, $1/(x^2+1)=(3-\sqrt{7})/2)$ gives you TWO real roots.

Comment: but if you see the question , it is saying all roots should be imaginary, for $z=\frac{3+\sqrt{7}}{2}$, x is imaginary and $z=\frac{3-\sqrt{7}}{2}$ , x is real

Comment: In fact this is the case $a=2$. ALL roots are not real for $a<1/2$, if $a\geq 1/2$ AT  LEAST one root is real.

Comment: @user3290550 Were my several answers of any help?

Comment: thanks so much ,your answer is correct, I was missing the point that if both roots cannot be real, then one root can be real and for $a>=\frac{1}{2}$ one root can be real. Thanks so much

Comment: @user3290550 I am happy that you appreciate my efforts. Please visit https://math.stackexchange.com/tour You can vote and/or accept an answer!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Factorizing your equation we get
$$x^4+x^2(2-3a)+1-2a=0$$
You can also write $$at^2-3at+1=0$$ where $t=\frac{1}{1+x^2}>0$
$a=0$ is impossible, so we get by the quadratic formula
$$t_{1,2}=-\frac{3}{2}\pm\sqrt{\frac{9}{4}-\frac{1}{a}}$$
If $$\frac{9}{4}-\frac{1}{a}<0$$ then the roots are imaginary.

Comment: No I solved the entire question, can you please see that, my answer is slighly not matching